# Is there a way to read the name of the main xml tag in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have 2 xml files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc300:TEST xmlns:iabc="http://www.isa.com/iabc/1_0/basic/schema" xmlns:abc300="http://www.isa.com/iabc/1_0/abc300/schema" >
        <abc300:Header>
            <abc300:AbcCode>111</abc300:AbcCode>
        </abc300:Header>
</abc300:TEST>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc301:TEST xmlns:iabc="http://www.isa.com/iabc/1_0/basic/schema" xmlns:abc300="http://www.isa.com/iabc/1_0/abc301/schema" >
    <abc301:Header>
        <abc301:AbcCode>111</abc301:AbcCode>
    </abc301:Header>
</abc301:TEST>
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to get the **abc300** or **abc301** nametag via C#, so I can see (by program) which xml file the user used.
Already thanks.

Comment: Note that this isn't the name of the element - it's the alias for the *namespace* of the element. Have you tried anything yet? It should be fairly easy to get the actual namespace (e.g. "http://www.isa.com/iabc/1_0/abc301/schema") in LINQ to XML, for example.

Comment: There are a number of questions about this; have you looked at any of them? For instance, [XML Element and Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452888/215552), [How do I get the XML root node with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4498423/215552)

Comment: Yes I tried a lot but that didn't work. Also the links above I still don't get the alias.
If I use the following code:

var test = _vm.XmlDoc.DocumentElement;
var t2 = test.Attributes;

t2 gives back a few attributes but still I don't know how to get the alias 'abc300' or 'abc301'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication170
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            string rootStr = doc.Root.Name.LocalName;
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.Name.Namespace;
            string prefix = root.GetPrefixOfNamespace(ns);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that this was possible.